# Need help getting launch daemon working on macOS

Tags: macos, plist, launchd

I have a launch daemon that I just can't get to work.  It's supposed to run a script every day at 3 AM.  The script works and I can run it manually without sudo.  See below for the launch daemon (com.rsync.plist) and the output of the commands I ran to start it. If anyone has any ideas why it won't run, I would really appreciate it.

'''

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
                <key>Label</key>
                <string>com.rsync</string>
                <key>Program</key>
                <string>/Users/xserve10/Documents/rsync.sh</string>
                <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>Hour</key>
                        <integer>3</integer>
                        <key>Minute</key>
                        <integer>0</integer>
                </dict>
        </dict>
</plist>


Xserve-10s-Mac-mini:Documents xserve10$ ls /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.rsync.plist
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.rsync.plist
Xserve-10s-Mac-mini:Documents xserve10$ sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.rsync.plist
Password:
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.rsync.plist: service already loaded
Load failed: 37: Operation already in progress
```

'''

Comment: The file seems to be already loaded, try unloading it first with `sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.rsync.plist`.

Comment: I've tried that several times.  I've also tried setting it in my local LaunchAgents folder, still not working.

Comment: I'd recommend that you move `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.rsync.plist` elsewhere, restart your Mac, copy `rsync.plist` back to `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` and run `sudo launchctl load` again. You may want to  name `com.rsync.plist` differently, for example `local.rsync.plist`, to make it clear that you aren't running an "official" rsync plist, but a modified one.

Comment: You may be running into privacy protection on the user's Documents folder; see ["What and how does macOS Mojave implement to restrict applications access to personal data?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673) and ["How to run a LaunchAgent that runs a script which causes failures because of System Integrity Protection"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338213). Try moving it (and any other files it accesses) outside the user's home folder.

Comment: Thanks, I tried moving it to /Library/Scripts, I'll see if it works tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

- sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.rsync.plist
- sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.rsync.plist

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).